# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{(a+i\omega)^{n+1}}\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}\omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, partial-fractions

I would like to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{(a+i\omega)^{n+1}}\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}\omega,$$
where $i$ is the imaginary number and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are constants.

I have tried to perform a binomial expansion of the denominator where the even indices will represent the real part and the odd indices the imaginary part. From that I can calculate the real and imaginary parts of the fraction but then I have also to calculate the squared term which makes the integrand very messy and I cannot see anyway of evaluating the integral.

I have also tried to use partial fractions, such as,
$$\left|\frac{1}{(a+i\omega)^{n+1}}\right|^2 = \frac{1}{(a+i\omega)^{n+1}(a-i\omega)^{n+1}} = \frac{A}{(a+i\omega)^{1}}+\frac{B\omega+C}{(a+i\omega)^{2}}+...$$
but again things start to get super-messy and very difficult to solve.

**Question:**

Is there are any trick to solve this integral?
Or, should I still follow one of the two methods I have described?

Comment: The change of variable $$\omega=a\tan t$$ yields $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{(a+i\omega)^{n+1}}\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}\omega=\frac1{|a|^{2n-1}}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}t\,dt$$ and you might recognize the integral on the RHS as $2W_{2n}$ where $(W_n)$ denotes the sequence of [Wallis integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals), whose values are known.

Comment: or just realize that $|z|^q=|z^q|$.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless, I still cannot see how do you get rid of the complex number $1+i\tan t$. By the way, the factor should be $1/(|a|^{2n+1})$, no?

Comment: Re the factor $1/|a|^{2n+1}$: indeed, well spotted, silly me! Re the complex number, simply note that $|1+i\tan t|^2=1/\cos^2t$ and that $d\omega=|a|dt/\cos^2t$.

Comment: Yes, sure. I forgot about the absolute value. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier Transform of $f(t)=e^{-a\omega}u(t)$ is $F(\omega)=\dfrac{1}{a+j\omega}$. Also we know that $$FT((-jt)^nf(t))=F^{(n)}(\omega)$$from the other side$$F^{(n)}(\omega)=\dfrac{(-j)^nn!}{(a+j\omega)^{n+1}}$$therefore according to Parseval's identity we have $$\int_{\Bbb R}|f(t)|^2dt=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega$$hence by substitution we obtain:$$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{2n}e^{-2at}dt=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega=\dfrac{(n!)^2}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}|\dfrac{1}{(a+j\omega)^{n+1}}|^2d\omega$$which means that$$\int_{\Bbb R}|\dfrac{1}{(a+j\omega)^{n+1}}|^2d\omega=\dfrac{2\pi\Gamma(2n+1)}{(2a)^{2n+1}\Gamma^2(n+1)}$$here is a sketch of integral for $a=1$

[image]

where red square markers indicate on when $n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: $n$ may be not an integer.

Comment: @Szeto, it is true but in my example it is an integer. I will edit it.

Comment: Please avoid the unnecessary uses of `\LARGE`, they only make your answer look childish. Oh, and the power of $a$ in your formula is incorrect, already for homogeneity reasons.

Comment: Now, the computation and the final result itself are probably also off by a factor depending on $n$, maybe something similar to $(2n)!/4^n$.

Comment: I do not understand why equality $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2at}dt=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}|F(\omega)|^2d\omega=\dfrac{(n!)^2}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}|\dfrac{1}{(a+j\omega)^{n+1}}|^2d\omega$$ holds. Where is $t^n$?

Comment: But one can see that users upvoting posts they did not understand or check, are prospering...

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.....My proof had a major flaw. I fixed it

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Maybe I am wrong but the solution should not be $$\frac{2\pi}{2a^{n+1}\Gamma(n+1)}$$?

Comment: No, sorry, your answer is OK.

Comment: Alright.hope it works for you...